# Como hacer Zoom en un grafo de GraphStream en javafx

Tags: java, javafx, graph

Tengo un grafo añadido a un ScrollPane pero este tiene muchos nodos, lo cual dificulta el análisis del mismo, esto me llevo a pensar en hacer  zoom y poder moverme interactivamente en el grafo, esto solo seria para hcer zoom, ya que para navegar en los ejes x y Y está el ScrollPane.

Esta pegunta puede considerarse duplicada del foro en inglés ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675827/how-to-zoom-into-a-graphstream-view/52929241#52929241))

Ahí doy por hecho que funciona e incluso he utilizado el codigo de la respuesta pero pues sin ningún resultado, tambien he utilizado ChatGpt y alguna que otra solución quedó libre de errores pero no funcionaron por el común denominador en todos mis intentos:
-error-

> *class org.graphstream.ui.fx_viewer.FxDefaultView cannot be cast to*
> *class java.awt.Component (org.graphstream.ui.fx_viewer.FxDefaultView*
> *is in module gs.ui.javafx@2.0 of loader 'app'; java.awt.Component is*
> *in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')*

Aquí esta el código:

```
@FXML
public void initialize(){
    //iprimir matriz en label
    matriz.setText(Arrays.deepToString(matrizRelacion));
    //crear grafo
    Graph graph = relaciones.printDigrafo(matrizRelacion);
    FxViewer viewer = new FxViewer(graph, FxViewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
    viewer.enableAutoLayout();
    View view = viewer.addDefaultView(false);
    FxViewPanel panel = (FxViewPanel) view;
    view.getCamera().setViewPercent(1);
    //zoom
    ((Component) view).addMouseWheelListener(e -> {
        e.consume();
        int i = e.getWheelRotation();
        double factor = Math.pow(1.25, i);
        Camera cam = view.getCamera();
        double zoom = cam.getViewPercent() * factor;
        Point2 pxCenter  = cam.transformGuToPx(cam.getViewCenter().x, cam.getViewCenter().y, 0);
        Point3 guClicked = cam.transformPxToGu(e.getX(), e.getY());
        double newRatioPx2Gu = cam.getMetrics().ratioPx2Gu/factor;
        double x = guClicked.x + (pxCenter.x - e.getX())/newRatioPx2Gu;
        double y = guClicked.y - (pxCenter.y - e.getY())/newRatioPx2Gu;
        cam.setViewCenter(x, y, 0);
        cam.setViewPercent(zoom);
    });
    //agregar al panel
    paneTabla.setContent(panel);
    //comprobaciones x
    relaciones.printRelaciones();

}
```

Como verán  aplique el codigo del foro en ingles y esto en teoría no debería dar ningún error pero a la hora de cargar el fxml a la scene, ha un monton de error incluido el ya mencionado siendo este la causa ya que al quitarlo todo funciona sin problemas.

-Warnings en el código:

> Casting 'view' to 'Component' will produce 'ClassCastException' for
> any non-null value

Supongo que es la causa de todo, pero no se como adaptarlo.
Cabe mencionar que con mis intentos anteriores si llegué mas lejos pero a la hora de hacer  el zoom 500 lineas de error me tiraba, decidí utilizar la respuesta de stack ya que parecia haber funcionado.

Sobre la documentacion de graphStream la mayoría  por no decir en su totalidad esta ejemplificada con Swing, alguno que otro con javaFx porque la gente preguntaba mucho.

Estaré agradecido si me ayudan a adaptar el código para que funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejemplo del foro inglés es para componentes del API Swing. Los componentes de JavaFX no tienen el método `addMouseWheelListener` (del API Swing) pero sí tienen `setOnScroll` (del API JavaFx, que detecta el movimiento de la rueda del mouse y el zooming en pantallas táctiles). Además, el ejemplo del foro inglés debería fallar porque no puedes cambiar el tipo de `View` a `Component`, son clases no relacionadas. De hecho, es el error que mencionas:

> class org.graphstream.ui.fx_viewer.**FxDefaultView cannot be cast to**
> class java.awt.**Component** (org.graphstream.ui.fx_viewer.FxDefaultView
> is in module gs.ui.javafx@2.0 of loader 'app'; java.awt.Component is
> in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')

Entonces, puedes usar `view.setOnScroll()` para ajustar matemáticas de la cámara cuando sucede un movimiento de la rueda del mouse. Por desgracia, el evento (de tipo `ScrollEvent`) no tiene información sobre cuántas veces has girado la rueda. Pero puedes usar una variable contadora con valor inicial a 0, en el método `setOnScrollStarted` reinicias la variable y en el método `setOnScroll` aumentas el valor en 1. He copiado tu lógica de zooming con los cambios necesarios. Seguro que algo debe refinarse, pero eso lo investigas.

Ejemplo:

```java
public class App extends Application {

  private Integer contadorScrollMouse = 0;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

    Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");
    graph.addNode("A");
    graph.addNode("B");
    graph.addNode("C");
    graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
    graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
    graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");

    FxViewer viewer = new FxViewer(graph, FxViewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
    FxViewPanel view = (FxViewPanel) viewer.addDefaultView(false);
    view.getCamera().setViewPercent(1);
    
    // reiniciar contador cuando inicia el movimiento
    view.setOnScrollStarted((event) -> {
      contadorScrollMouse = 0;
    });

    // contar movimientos de la rueda y ejecutar zooming
    // cuando sigue el movimiento
    view.setOnScroll((e) -> {
      contadorScrollMouse = contadorScrollMouse + 1;
      double factor = Math.pow(1.25, contadorScrollMouse);
      view.getCamera().setViewPercent(0.5);
      Camera cam = view.getCamera();
      double zoom = cam.getViewPercent() * factor;
      Point2 pxCenter = cam.transformGuToPx(cam.getViewCenter().x, cam.getViewCenter().y, 0);
      Point3 guClicked = cam.transformPxToGu(e.getX(), e.getY());
      double newRatioPx2Gu = cam.getMetrics().ratioPx2Gu / factor;
      double x = guClicked.x + (pxCenter.x - e.getX()) / newRatioPx2Gu;
      double y = guClicked.y - (pxCenter.y - e.getY()) / newRatioPx2Gu;
      cam.setViewCenter(x, y, 0);
      cam.setViewPercent(zoom);
    });

    viewer.enableAutoLayout();
    Parent parent = new BorderPane(view);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(parent, 400, 400));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();

  }
}
```

Comment: funcionoo jaja, lo el único detalle es que al estar en un ScrollPane el zoom y el desplazamiento de este se activan a la vez, pero supongo que se puede desactivar o simplemente cambiar a un pane simple, muchas gracias. Supongo que de haber sabido mas de javafx lo hubiera sacado pero queria lucirme contra mis compañeros jaja.